# How to split using SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to split `2009-02-27 14:30:53` in SQL Server in such a way that it turns to:

```
Y     M   D   T
-----------------------
2009  02  27  14:30:53
```

Can anyone please help me doing this using “Substring” and “Charindex”?

Comment: I would recommend using [`DatePart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) (or the similar shortcut functions `Year`, `Month`, `Day`.)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: No Sir I did some research before asking the question, but to tell the truth I am just a beginner. Actually I asked my question in a wrong way. I got a column of value like {(2009-02-27 14:30:53), (2008-02-27 14:31:53)...........(2010-02-27 10:31:53)} and I need to split that column into 4 column (Y, M, D, T). Actually I solved the problem (but I am not so sure whether it is OK or not specially it didn't work the way I thought and then I did some some trial and error and it gave the right result?).

Comment: The way I solved it like: SELECT tmc_code, Substring(measurement_tstamp, 1,Charindex('-', measurement_tstamp)-1) AS y, 
  Substring(measurement_tstamp, Charindex('-', measurement_tstamp)+1,Charindex('-', measurement_tstamp)-3) AS m,
  Substring(measurement_tstamp, Charindex('-', measurement_tstamp)+4,Charindex(' ', measurement_tstamp)-9) AS day,
  Substring(measurement_tstamp, Charindex(' ', measurement_tstamp), LEN(measurement_tstamp)) AS t FROM [reza].[dbo].[Sample_2]

Comment: Sorry for my bad english.........

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the following which uses the [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function and a [convert of the date](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) to return the time:

```
select
  datepart(year, yourDate) y,
  datepart(month, yourDate) m,
  datepart(day, yourDate) d,
  convert(char(8), yourdate, 108) t
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0155e2/1)

This could also be written to use [`YEAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx), [`MONTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) and [`DAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) functions:

```
select
  year(yourDate) y,
  month(yourDate) m,
  day(yourDate) d,
  convert(char(8), yourdate, 108) t
from yourtable
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0155e2/2)

Answer (score 0):

I **STRONGLY AGREE** that if you are a student, you NEED TO THINK FOR YOURSELF. If you are a student, this is not the right way to learn and you should try to do it yourself, research and talk to your peers. IF you are a student, this is the kind of attitude that contribute to the tons of crappy programmers in the market nowadays.

**BUT** if you are a working adult in search for a solution then I happen to have a generic StrSplit() function. You can use it like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.StrSplit('91,12,65,78,56,789',',')
```

or you can use it for your purpose:

```
SELECT  (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('2009-02-27','-') WHERE rowid=0) AS Y
        , (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('2009-02-27','-') WHERE rowid=1) AS M
        , (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('2009-02-27','-') WHERE rowid=2) AS D
        , (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('14:30:53',':') WHERE rowid=0) AS H
        , (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('14:30:53',':') WHERE rowid=1) AS M
        , (SELECT Element FROM dbo.StrSplit('14:30:53',':') WHERE rowid=2) AS S
```

Here is the definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StrSplit ( @pvsString VARCHAR(MAX), @pvsSeparator CHAR(1) )
RETURNS @fnorsList TABLE ([rowid] INT, [Element] NVARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @vsElement NVARCHAR(255)
    DECLARE @viPos INT
    DECLARE @viRow INT SET @viRow = 0

    WHILE CHARINDEX( @pvsSeparator, @pvsString) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @viPos  = CHARINDEX(@pvsSeparator, @pvsString)  
        SELECT @vsElement = SUBSTRING(@pvsString, 1, @viPos-1)

        INSERT INTO @fnorsList ([rowid], [Element]) SELECT @viRow, @vsElement
        SELECT @pvsString = SUBSTRING(@pvsString, @viPos+1, LEN(@pvsString)-@viPos)
        SET @viRow = @viRow + 1
    END
    INSERT INTO @fnorsList ([rowid], [Element]) SELECT @viRow, @vsElement
    RETURN
END
```